# How to upload multiple images/files with Javascript and Axios formdata

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, multipartform-data, form-data

In the attachment you can see my code. I want to be able to send more images from one submit. I am using Vue.js, Axios and Vanilla JS. In what way? My current code work perfectly,and I want a way to add more than one picture/file in this way that is picture on submit.

```
<div @drop="onDropFile($event)">
<label> Choose or drag file </label>
<input
   type="file"
   name="profile_image"
   @change="onChangeFile($event)">
</div>


onDropFile(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      let files = e.dataTransfer.files;
      this.createFile(files[0]);
    },

onChangeFile(e) {
  let files = e.target.files;
  this.product_image_data = e.target.files[0]
  this.createFile(files[0]);
},
createFile(file) {
  if (!file.type.match("image.*")) {
    alert("Select an image");
    return;
  }
  let reader = new FileReader();
  let vm = this;
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    vm.profile_image = e.target.result;
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

can you check this [laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/upload-multiple-files-and-relate-them-to-post-model) solution

```
...
data() {
    return {
        postFormData: new FormData(),
    };
},

methods: {
    onFileChange(event) {
        let files = e.target.files;          
        this.postFormData.append('images[]',files[0]);
        this.createFile(files[0]);
    },
...
```

Comment: My logic is little different but I try this